# Create Object on different server ASP

Tags: asp-classic, server

I want to create a temporary file on a different server as I'm on in ASP.

Here's my code I have:

```
<%
dim fs,fo,tfile,tname,mappad
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
response.Write("Path is "&Server.MapPath("\tmp"))
Set fo=fs.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("\tmp"))
tname=fs.GetTempName
mappad=Server.MapPath("tmp\")
set tfile=fo.CreateTextFile(tname,false)
tfile.WriteLine(Server.MapPath("\tmp")&tname)
tfile.close
 response.Write("file "&tname&" created succesfully")
set tfile=nothing
set fo=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
```

Problem is I'm writing in my root-map but I need to write in a different map which is on the network. This is because IT-department doens't want us developers to write directly on the website. So instead of *C://inetpub/wwwroot* (which is my local test-server ofc.) I want to write to *C://wwdb/images*. In production envirement it should change from *intranet.mydomain.com* to *\network\appdata\images*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use absolute paths instead of server.mappath - eg `Set fo=fs.GetFolder("C:\wwdb\images")`.  You need to make sure your IUSR account has write permission on the folder you want to write to.

Comment: @John better post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute paths instead of server.mappath - eg `Set fo=fs.GetFolder("C:\wwdb\images")`.

Remember to give your IUSR account permission to write to your target folder

(Posting my comment as an answer as suggested by Shadow Wizard)